# unable to redirect to a particular url

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Hi I am building a web site.
here requirement is to build a url like

```
http://localhost:10080/edit/?d=2014-02-22%2015:36:38.688000
```

and it have to be processed bu application

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                       ('/edit',EditPost),
                                       ('/',HomePage),
                                       ('/post',PostPosting),                                      
                                       ], debug=True)
```

I am using above but its not recognizing EditPost class

my app.yaml is

```
application: your-app-id-indoor
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IndoorBlog.application


- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

---could some one help me please...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your `webapp2.WSGIApplication` Class, you are handling edit url as `http://localhost:8080/edit` not `/edit/`.

If you need to handle this url `http://localhost:10080/edit/?d=2014-02-22%2015:36:38.688000`, 
then `webapp2.WSGIApplication` class should be like this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                       ('/edit/',EditPost),
                       ('/',HomePage),
                       ('/post',PostPosting),                                      
                      ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Webapp2 routing has named routes for redirect_to:

Docs: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect_to